# Array con PHP para almacenar consulta

Tags: php, mysql, array

espero por favor su ayuda.
Tengo la siguiente consulta

Y quisiera almacenar el resultado, es decir varios nombres y apellidos en un ARRAY, para después mostrar el resultado del Array en excel creado con libreria PHPSPREADSHEET.

```
$squery3= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT nombres, apellidos FROM form_7_docente WHERE id_formulario_7 = $id_formulario_7");

$roww8 =8;

while($data2 = mysqli_fetch_object($squery3))
{
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('P'.$roww8, $data2->nombres.' '.$data2->apellidos);
    $roww8++;
}
```

Comment: En php, al ejecutar una consulta, ya está se devuelve en formato de array. De echo, para que puedas comprobarlo, si hacer un echo var_dump o un print_r de $squery verás que devuelve un array. Si tu eso quieres descomponerlo para meterlo en un array, es decir extraer de tu query el objeto nombre de la base de datos, deberías acceder a $squery[0]->nombre y esto debes de hacerlo dentro de un ciclo foreach para automatizar el proceso. También te aconsejo que en vez de usar mysqli uses PDO

Comment: Gracias por responder, efectivamente datos es un array, lo que necesito es imprimir todo lo que obtenga de la consulta, es por eso que pense en un array, ya que el problema que tengo es que con el While solo imprimo un dato y el resto los reemplaza

Comment: Hola! Bienvenido a SOes. El código se comparte como texto, siempre. De la misma forma que no te vamos a dar soluciones en imágenes, para que no tengas que transcribirlas. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: El código, como está en el `while`, debería ser correcto. Lo único por lo que podría estar ¿fallando? es porque hay una sola fila y piensas que hay más, o porque la biblioteca (PHPExcel o PHPSpreadsheet) te exige agregar varias filas a una hoja de un modo específico. Puedes depurar haciendo un `echo` de cada valor por ejemplo... Conviene que indiques en la pregunta qué biblioteca usas. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta y de paso, cambia la imagen por el texto del código.

Comment: Con respecto a la consulta, estoy seguro de que tiene varios valores y es por eso que queria probar almacenando todo el resultado de la query en otra variable Array para despues mostrar los valores, pero la verdad no se muy bien como hacerlo..